# C#. Pattern for dynamic report creation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, solid

This is a simplified example, the actual problem has more reports and data points that are requested. Also, more reports could be added in the future so I would like to have something "smart" and dynamic.

Let's say I have the following methods:

```
public CustomerInfo GetCustomerInfo(int customerId){/* implementation */ }
public AccountInfo GetAccountInfo(int customerId){/* implementation */ }
public BankInfo GetBankInfo(int bankId){/* implementation */ }
```

I have three reports:

```
Report1 -> Needs CustomerInfo, AccountInfo
Report2 -> Needs CustomerInfo, AccountInfo
Report3 -> Needs AccountInfo, BankInfo
```

Without doing if/else or any other sequential logic, how can I determine which methods need to be called for a given report list that will have 1 to N reports requested?

Right now I've got something similar to this:

```
// I receive a list of reports to print for a particular client
var reports = new List<string> { "Report1", "Report2" }; // we get this as a param in a method
var int clientId = 12345; // we get this as a param in a method

//method implementation
foreach(var report in reports)
{
    var model = new ReportModel
    {
        CustomerInfo = GetCustomerInfo(clientId),
        AccountInfo = GetAccountInfo(clientId),
        BankInfo = GetBankInfo(bankId)
    }

    PrintReport(model);
}
```

Problem with this approach is that the same three methods get called 3 times even though

1. we don't need to call all of them (BankInfo is unnecessary for
   Report1 and Report2) so that call is wasted.
2. we call GetCustomerInfo and GetAccountInfo get called twice when it
   should've been called once, it's the same data shared for both
   reports.

How can I improve this to be smarter about what methods need to be called. Is there a pattern I could use?

Comment: What exactly is a `ReportModel` in your lexicon here?  It seems like your three `*Info` classes are *model* types.  So I'm not sure if `ReportModel` is a super-type (parent class)? or an aggregation? Or what?

Comment: It sounds like you need a factory pattern for your report models.  NOTE: your example does not distinguish the model for the specific type of report, or even store the report type in a property.  The factory can select the specific report model and provide the necessary values based on the provided information (i.e. report name, clientId and bankId).

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I think I understand what you are saying but I'm not quite sure, so excuse me if my answer is wrong. By having a Report1Model and Report2Model, let's assume they both need CustomerName which is obtained by GetCustomerInfo. Using a factory pattern to select the specific report model, how can I avoid having two calls to GetCustomerInfo?

Comment: @Tersosauros The *Info methods return DTOs. The ReportModel is just a class that collects every piece of information needed to print a report.

Comment: @ornstai, it's no different than what you have in your example, but your more specific models have exactly the info they need and no more.  The alternative is to get your `*Info` before the loop and pass those in to your factory method.  The only way to eliminate multiple calls to `Get*Info()` is to do it before the loop starts.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect I'm missing something in your question, as the solution seems rather obvious: create `model`, once, prior to looping through the reports.

```
//method implementation
var model = new ReportModel
{
    CustomerInfo = GetCustomerInfo(clientId),
    AccountInfo = GetAccountInfo(clientId),
    BankInfo = GetBankInfo(bankId)
}

foreach(var report in reports)
{

    PrintReport(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think what you're looking for is [Lazy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var model = new ReportModel
{
    CustomerInfo = new Lazy<CustomerInfo>( () => GetCustomerInfo() ),
    AccountInfo = new Lazy<AccountInfo>( () => GetAccountInfo(clientId) ),
    BankInfo = new Lazy<BankInfo>( () => GetBankInfo(bankId) )
};
Console.WriteLine(model.BankInfo.Value.AccountNumber); //Call isn't made until this line executes
```

Now all three pieces of data are available from the model, but if the caller doesn't use some of them, they won't actually get populated and won't cause any overhead. Well, a tiny bit. Almost none.

Just beware of [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595482/what-are-closures-in-c) if you are passing arguments (e.g. `clientId`). They won't be evaluated until the call is executed.